# Disable Enable Trigger SQL server for a table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want to create one proc like below but it has error on syntax.
Could anyone pointing out the problem?

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_proc] AS

BEGIN

DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.tr_name ON dbo.table_name

-- some update statement

ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.tr_name  ON dbo.table_name

END

** Error Message : Incorrect syntax near 'ENABLE'.
```

Answer (score 286, accepted):

use the following commands instead:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE TRIGGER tr_name

ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE TRIGGER tr_name
```

Comment: what versions of SqlServer is this good for? not working for me, while `DISABLE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_name] on [schema].[table_name]` worked

Comment: Your answer is correct. But actually @pang statements don't need any fix instead of a simple `;`! I prefer to use `ENABLE Trigger`. It's applicable on all SQL Servers starting with 2008.

Comment: If you need to do all the tables in a database use this:

EXECUTE sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? disable trigger ALL"
go

Answer (score 81):

The line before needs to end with a `;` because in SQL `DISABLE` [is not a keyword](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/307937/msft-mso-disable-trigger-statement-not-compiling-within-a-sp-however-it-executes-just-fine-outside). For example:

```
BEGIN
;
DISABLE TRIGGER ...
```

Comment: I much prefer this answer. It addresses the problem and gives the solution instead of a workaround. While workarounds have their place, it is important to understand why an error occurred instead of blindly following a workaround with no context.

Answer (score 14):

As Mark mentioned, the previous statement should be ended in semi-colon. So you can use:

```
; DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.tr_name ON dbo.table_name
```

Answer (score 5):

After the ENABLE TRIGGER OR DISABLE TRIGGER in a new line write GO, Example:

```
DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.tr_name ON dbo.table_name

GO
-- some update statement

ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.tr_name  ON dbo.table_name

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the Dynamic Script to enable or disable the Triggers.

```
select 'alter table '+ (select Schema_name(schema_id) from sys.objects o 
where o.object_id = parent_id) + '.'+object_name(parent_id) + ' ENABLE TRIGGER '+
Name as EnableScript,*
from sys.triggers t 
where is_disabled = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share something that helped me out. Idea credit goes to @Siavash and @Shahab Naseer.

I needed something where I could script disable and re enable of triggers for a particular table. I normally try and stay away from tiggers, but sometimes they could be good to use.

I took the script above and added a join to the sysobjects so I could filter by table name. This script will disable a trigger or triggers for a table.

```
select 'alter table '+ (select Schema_name(schema_id) from sys.objects o 
where o.object_id = parent_id) + '.'+object_name(parent_id) + ' ENABLE TRIGGER '+ t.Name as EnableScript,*
from sys.triggers t 
INNER JOIN dbo.sysobjects DS ON DS.id = t.parent_id 
where is_disabled = 0 AND DS.name = 'tblSubContact'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO

-- HABILITAR TRIGGERS
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ['+ 
    ( SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) FROM [sys].[objects] AS O WHERE O.[object_id] = T.[parent_id]) 
        + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(T.[parent_id]) + '] ENABLE TRIGGER '+ T.[name] + ';' AS [EnableScript], *
        FROM [sys].[triggers] AS T 
            INNER JOIN [sys].[sysobjects] DS ON DS.[id] = T.[parent_id]
        WHERE T.[is_disabled] = 0 
            --AND DS.[name] = 'TableName'

-- DESHABILITAR TRIGGERS
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ['+ 
    ( SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) FROM [sys].[objects] AS O WHERE O.[object_id] = T.[parent_id]) 
        + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(T.[parent_id]) + '] DISABLE TRIGGER '+ T.[name] + ';' AS [EnableScript], *
        FROM [sys].[triggers] AS T 
            INNER JOIN [sys].[sysobjects] DS ON DS.[id] = T.[parent_id]
        WHERE T.[is_disabled] = 0 
            --AND DS.[name] = 'TableName'
```

Answer (score 0):

-- HABILITAR TRIGGERS
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ['+
( SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) FROM [sys].[objects] AS O WHERE O.[object_id] = T.[parent_id])
+ '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(T.[parent_id]) + '] ENABLE TRIGGER '+ T.[name] + ';' AS [EnableScript], *
FROM [sys].[triggers] AS T
INNER JOIN [sys].[sysobjects] DS ON DS.[id] = T.[parent_id]
WHERE T.[is_disabled] = 1  --  Must be 1, not 0 --
--AND DS.[name] = 'TableName'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Buffer States:

Pinned: Currently used.
Clean: Meaning the buffer is now unpinned and is a candidate for immediate aging out if the current (data blocks) are not referenced again. The contents are either in synch with disk or the buffer contains a CR snapshot of a block.
Free/Unused:  Meaning the buffer is empty because the instance just started. This state is very similar to Clean, except that the buffer has not been used.
Dirty: Buffer is no longer pinned but the contents (data block) have changed and must be flushed to disk by DBWn before it can be aged out.
Three Buffer Pool:

Keep
Recycle
Default
Database Buffer Cache Parameter:

DB_CACHE_SIZE (BLOCK SIZE will be the size declare in DB_BLOCK_SIZE)
DB_KEEP_CACHE_SIZE
DB_2K_CACHE_SIZE
DB_4K_CACHE_SIZE
DB_8K_CACHE_SIZE
DB_16K_CACHE_SIZE
DB_32K_CACHE_SIZE
DB_RACYCLE_CACHE_SIZE
DB_BLOCK_SIZE(Default Block size which can not be changed later anyway)

SHOW PARAMETER DB_BLOCK_SIZE;

show parameter db_cache_size;

Answer (score -1):

Below is the simplest way

Try the code

`ALTER  TRIGGER trigger_name  DISABLE`

That's it :)

Comment: Not working on SQL Server > 2008 R2 and the question is for MS SQL Server

Answer (score -1):

if you want to execute ENABLE TRIGGER Directly From Source :

we can't write like this:

```
Conn.Execute "ENABLE TRIGGER trigger_name ON table_name"
```

instead, we can write :

```
Conn.Execute "ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE TRIGGER trigger_name"
```