# SQL Server: Don´t execute a Trigger when the updater is another trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Here is the  scenario:
There is Trigger A and Trigger B, both in the Person table. I can't trigger the Trigger A when the update on table Person comes from Trigger B.

Is there something, such as an IF that I could use to solve this situation?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are the triggers setting values in Person that could be solved by instead making the given column computed? Some schema info, and the triggers would help give more meaningful answers.

Comment: Why do you need to update the table at all when you're updating it currently anyway? Couldn't you include what the trigger does in the update-statement? Triggers are often the root of all evil, use stored-procedures. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers

Comment: Are nested triggers used in other scenarios (and are they valid)?  If not, you could [disable nested triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178101(v=sql.105).aspx) at the server level.

Comment: Firstly I don't like triggers at all. Secondly the first trigger is in the Person table and the second is not. And I don´t have access to the source code, I just know that this field is used. Thanks for the suggestions! I will be trying to apply them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

```
IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(OBJECT_ID('TRIGGER_NAME')) = 0
BEGIN

    -- Your Trigger STuff

END
```

Thanks for answers and comments.

Answer (score 1):

Right at the start, I will warn you that having multiple triggers on one table is not a good idea. Try and merge the actions of the two triggers into one if possible. However, if that is not a solution for you, then read on for my version. (I am not certain if it is practically valid, but go ahead and give it a shot anyway)

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerB
ON yourtable 
FOR UPDATE 
AS 
    BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE TRIGGER triggerA
    --your processing
    ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE TRIGGER triggerA
    END
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388072/disable-enable-trigger-sql-server) deals with disabling then enabling triggers inside a stored procedure. This is an application of the same in a trigger.

**Disclaimer:** I am counting on this to fail because altering a table while in a trigger defined on that same table seems like an impossible task. But I have no resources at hand to test my wacky theory, so please test it and let me know if I'm thinking too far outside the box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will be trying it!

Comment: Let me know what happens.

Comment: I just noticed your last comment on the question. I think if the two triggers are on different tables, that should allow my proposed solution to work without an issue IMO.

Comment: Note that you may have a potential race condition in a multi-user situation unless you're serializing access somewhere along the way.  For example:  User 1 causes TriggerB to execute, which disables TriggerA on TableA.  User 2 inserts directly into TableA, expecting the now-disabled trigger to fire... but it won't.  You can get some subtle, hard-to-find-and-fix bugs this way.

Comment: pmbAustin is right. In a high user traffic period, this bug could manifest quite frequently. Do consider that possibility, Andre Luiz.

Comment: @CodeNewbie No. I saw some danger in it. I did the tests and it worked all ok but then I realized that it is common to disable and enable triggers in the project that I´m working. Thus I decided not to do so. What happened is that I got the source code, which I didn't have before and I replaced the field by a computed field and took off the updates in this fields. By the way. Thanks everyone for  answering and commenting in this question!